# How to get the original value of changed fields?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, insert-update

I'm using sqlalchemy as my orm, and use `declarative` as Base.

```
Base = declarative_base()
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

My question is, how do I know a user has been modified, and how to get the original values without query database again?

```
user = Session.query(User).filter_by(id=user_id).first()
# some operations on user
....
# how do I know if the user.name has been changed or not?
...
# How do get the original name?
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE**

I found a method `get_history` can get the history value of a field, but I'm not sure if it is the correct method for my purpose.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import get_history
user = Session.query(User).first()
print user.name  # 'Jack'
print get_history(user, 'name') # ((),['Jack'],())

user.name = 'Mike'
print get_history(user, 'name') # (['Mike'], (),['Jack'])
```

So, we can check the value of `get_history`, but is it the best method?

Comment: I think `get_history` is the correct method. It's a documented public function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

\To see if `user` has been modified you can check if `user in session.dirty`. If it is and you want to undo it, you can execute

```
session.rollback()
```

but be advised that this will rollback everything for the session to the last `session.commit()`.

If you want to get the original values and memory serves me correctly, it's the second element of the tuple returned by the `sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.get_history` utility function. You would have to do

```
old_value = sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.get_history(user, 'attribute')[2]
```

for each attribute that you want.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how to get the original value?

Comment: @Freewind. Sorry I missed that in the answer when that was the point. updated.

Comment: thank you again :) I think I can use it now. And, as I tried, we should get the third element if the attribute had been modified. Please edit your answer if I'm right(just to let others see the correct answer)