# How to get the original value of changed fields in sqlalchemy after session.flush()?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flush

I have a little problem similar to [Getting fields history before flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645802/how-to-get-the-original-value-of-changed-fields)

Here is my code:

```
user = User.query.filter(User.id == user_id).first()

print(user.first_name)
# Rick

user.first_name = 'Anders'

print(get_history(user, 'first_name')) 
# History(added=[u'Anders'], unchanged=(), deleted=[u'Rick'])

db.session.flush()

print(get_history(user, 'first_name')) 
# History(added=(), unchanged=[u'Anders'], deleted=())
```

So, I can easily get the original value before flush. I can use get_history and the 'dirty' attribute of a session. But when I do session.flush() this method shows an incorrect result and the 'dirty' is empty.

However, I can rollback these changes using session.rollback() after session.flush().
That's why I think it's possible to get the original values. They just hide somewhere.

But where?

Answer (score 1):

> session.flush() writes out all pending object creations, deletions and modifications to the database as INSERTs, DELETEs, UPDATEs, etc

So when you call `session.flush()` your objects which you add session(`session.add(object)`) goes to the database but they arent write permanently until a commit(`session.commit()`) or a rollback happen.

The answer for your question: your objects are in database with `session.flush()`

Comment: but how does a rollback get a previous state of an object?

So, I performed `session.flush()`, my changes went to the database. 
And both states the previous and the current ones are stored in there. Do I understand it correctly? 

But can I get the previous state without performing a rollback?
Like `user.get_history_after_flush()`

Comment: I don't database servers manage it but yes when you call flush() changes goes to the database. There is something to notice; this changes only available to that session. It means this changes won't be retrieve with another session. If you do a commit then you can't back previous values.