# How to get the old value stored in database in an uncommitted SQLAlchemy Session?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

1. Query a user from database:

   ```
   user1 = db.session.query(User).filter_by(id=1).first()
   ```
2. Update the user1, such as:

   ```
   user1.username = 'a'
   ```
3. Query the user again:

   ```
   user2 = db.session.query(User).filter_by(id=1).first()
   ```

Now `user2.username` equals `user1.username`, the new value. So after step 2 how can I get the old username stored in database?

Comment: you mean after step 3 user2.username is a

Comment: yes, in step3  user2.username == user1.username

Comment: Without comitting?

Comment: Do a rollback, or a commit. What's the use case for this?

Comment: Related, or a duplicate of [How to get the original value of changed fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645802/how-to-get-the-original-value-of-changed-fields). There are 2 things at play here that are not mentioned in the other Q/A: identity map and autoflush. In order to keep queries consistent with the SQLAlchemy Session's state, an automatic flush is performed before queries. And even if you disable that, when SQLAlchemy sees that the primary key of the returned row is in the Session's identity map, it just returns the existing object. Do `user1 is user2` and check the result.

Comment: This is btw a surprisingly [common question](https://www.google.fi/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+sqlalchemy+session+get+old+value&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).