# Old value not in history of Mutable numpy array in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, numpy, sqlalchemy, mutable

I'm trying to write a version history of a numpy array that I store in my database. Everytime I edit the array and commit it to the database, I want to save the previous, unedited version of the array in a separate table. I store the numpy array in a PickleType column and I've written a wrapper class with the Mutable mixin to detect changes to the array.

With the MutableNumpy class that I've written, I can detect changes to the array (i.e. the row appears in `session.dirty` and the updated value appears in `inspect(row).attrs.data.history.added`). However, I'm having trouble accessing the original, unmodified version of the array, which I need to capture for the version history. Other questions like [How to get the original value of changed fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645802/how-to-get-the-original-value-of-changed-fields) suggest that the original value should show up in the `deleted` part of the history, and the example for [Versioning objects on the SQL documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/examples.html#module-examples.versioned_history) also appears to use the `deleted` attribute of `get_history` to access the old value.

I've explored using `active_history=True` for [column_property](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.column_property), but this hasn't been fruitful yet. I've also checked that `session.rollback()` restores the unedited array, so I know the unedited array is available somewhere.

Here is a minimum working example, with the MutableNumpy wrapper class, a simple table definition, and a few database operations to illustrate the issue.

```
import numpy as np
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import Mutable
from sqlalchemy.types import PickleType


Base = declarative_base()

class MutableNumpy(Mutable, np.ndarray):
    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls, key, value):
        "Convert plain numpy arrays to MutableNumpy."
        if not isinstance(value, MutableNumpy):
            if isinstance(value, np.ndarray):
                mutable_array = MutableNumpy(shape=value.shape, dtype=value.dtype, buffer=value)
                return mutable_array

            # this call will raise ValueError
            return Mutable.coerce(key, value)
        else:
            return value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        "Detect array set events and emit change events."
        np.ndarray.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        self.changed()

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        "Detect array del events and emit change events."
        np.ndarray.__delitem__(self, key)
        self.changed()

    def __getstate__(self):
        d = self.__dict__.copy()
        d.pop('_parents', None)
        return d

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(MutableNumpy.as_mutable(PickleType))

from sqlalchemy import inspect
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///tmp.db', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
sess = Session()

row = MyTable(data=np.zeros((2, 2), dtype=int))
sess.add(row)
sess.commit()

row.data[0,0] = 1
hist = inspect(row).attrs.data.history
print(hist.added)  # Shows [[1, 0], [0, 0]] as expected
print(hist.unchanged)  # Empty as expected
print(hist.deleted)  # Does NOT show the original array [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```